# Why i can't change the font for div in my css?

Tags: html, css

When I specify the font in body style in CSS it works ok. But when I do the same for div it has no effect.

```
.tel {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    height: 60px;
    padding: 30px 30px 0 0;
    font: 24pt/0.64 "Consolas", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 87.5%;
    width: cover;
}
```

Comment: And you have the "consolas" webfont ?

Comment: i linked it in header

Comment: Compatability: Win: 82.97% Mac: 34.77%

Comment: Have a look in inspect element where it is getting the font size from. You may have a class below this that is overwriting it. If this is happening then I recommend putting this class under the overwriting class if possible, if not use !important, but you don't want to use that too much, I try to use no !important's if possible, your code should evolve and not be modified unless there's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i needed to use styling like this

```css
.tel a{
 font: 24pt/0.64 "Consolas", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: white;
 padding: 0 0 0 50px;
}
```

Comment: Now read your question and think did we have any chance of answering your question with what you provided and try to improve your questions in future please

Comment: So basically a tags had a font size somewhere further up in your css. Next time add some HTML too so we can have a better understanding of wheat is going on.

Answer (score 0):

try with !important and see if it has an effect, if so, an other class is applied on your DIV.